# The hydrogen ion in acidified potassium manganate (VII)

Tags: redox

Recently, I am playing with redox reaction and I come over a compound acidified potassium manganate (VII) ($\ce{KMnO4/H^+}$). I get confused that why they put $\ce{H^+}$ beside $\ce{KMnO4}$. Doesn't the hydrogen ions flow freely in the solution or something else.

And so, when we are writing a chemical reaction with occur $\ce{KMnO4}$, we sometimes exclude the $\ce{H^+}$. Why that so?

Comment: Permanganic acid ($\ce{HMnO4}$) is a strong acid, so it's not easy to form via protonation of  $\ce{MnO4^{-}}$. When adding permanganate ions to very *very* acidic mixtures, for example pure liquid $\ce{H2SO4}$, you can consider that the reaction $\ce{MnO4^{-} + H^+ <=> HMnO4}$ happens to an appreciable extent, producing permanganic acid. In the specific case I mentioned, however, $\ce{HMnO4}$ is a short lived entity, as it is quickly dehydrated by the sulfuric acid to form the anhydride $\ce{Mn2O7}$, [a very reactive species](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2A3jVDxwPw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have known that the permanganate(VII) ion is a strong oxidizing agent because manganese is in the highest +7 oxidation state.

But in different pH conditions, $\ce{MnO_4^-}$ Will be reduced to different product:

1. In a **acidic** solution, it is reduced to the colourless manganese(II) ion, $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$.
   $\ce{8H^+ + MnO_4^{−} + 5e^{−} → Mn^{2+} + 4H_2O}$
2. In a **strongly basic** solution, it is reduced to the green manganate ion, $\ce{MnO_4^{2−}}$.
   $\ce{MnO_4^{−} + e^{−} → MnO_4^{2−}}$
3. In a **neutral** solution, it is reduced to the brown manganese dioxide $\ce{MnO_2}$.
   $\ce{2H_2O + MnO_4^{−} + 3e^{−} → MnO_2 + 4OH^{−}}$

But the more understandable way to say, I think, is that $\ce{MnO_4^-}$ can be reduced to different oxidation states; however, it is an idea about chemical balance. If there is $\ce{H^+}$, the first reaction dominates (since we put in more reactant). While if there is $\ce{OH^-}$, neither reaction 1 nor 3 happens (1: lack of reactant; 3: too many product), so the third dominates.

Hope this helps.

Addition: in those different reactions, there are also different tendency to take place and make $\ce{MnO_4^-}$ reduced. In fact, the first reaction (happening with acidic solution) have a much larger tendency to take place. Thus, if $\ce{H^+}$ presents, $\ce{MnO_4^-}$ will have a larger tendency to oxidate other compounds. Thus some reactions require $\ce{MnO_4^-}$ with $\ce{H^+}$ instead of only $\ce{MnO_4^-}$.